# Trying to render my LINQ query to a razor view

Tags: asp.net, razor

Good evening all.

I created a join using between three tables, one of which is a junction table.
I used a combination of LinqPad and Linquer to test my LINQ query.
My C# code doesnt generate an error and my two item fields (Product_ID, Title) are rendered just fine. 
What Im trying to do is render the contents from the other table (tblAuthor.FirstName) with razor.

```
// GET: TestProducts
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = (from pd in db.tblProducts
                 join od in db.tblAuthorProducts on pd.Product_ID equals od.Product_ID
                 orderby pd.Product_ID
                 select new
                 {
                     pd.Title,
                     pd.Description,
                     pd.Start_FY,
                     pd.ProductType,
                     od.tblAuthor.FirstName,
                     od.tblAuthor.LastName
                 }).ToList();

        return View(products.ToList());



        // Original effort
        //var tblProduct = db.tblProducts.Include(t => t.tblAuthorProducts);
        //var products = (from prod in db.tblProducts
        //                join auProd in db.tblAuthorProducts on prod.Product_ID equals auProd.Product_ID
        //                join au in db.tblAuthors on auProd.Author_ID equals au.Author_ID

        //                orderby prod.Product_ID
        //                select new
        //                {
        //                    ProductID = prod.Product_ID,
        //                    Title = prod.Title,
        //                    Author = au.LastName,

        //                }).ToList();
        //return View(products.ToList());
        //var tblTitles = db.tblTitles.Include(t => t.tblAuthor).Include(t => t.tblRegion);
    }

//Desired render

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Product ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)

{

    <tr>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            // LastName
        </td>
        </tr>
}
</table>
```

So I tested my LINQ query in a Console app and all the information I was seeking to join worked fine.

```
// LINQ
var products = (from pd in db.tblProducts
join aupd in db.tblAuthorProducts on pd.Product_ID equals aupd.Product_ID
join au in db.tblAuthors on aupd.Author_ID equals au.Author_ID
orderby pd.Product_ID
select new
{
pd.Title,
pd.Description,
pd.Start_FY,
pd.ProductType,
au.FirstName,
au.LastName
}).ToList();

foreach (var item in products)
{
Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So Im still using the same model.
Once I did the above and set my return View(products); I was able to access the tblAuthor fields.

Comment: Hi Hommy, welcome to stackoverflow. I think it could be helpful to provide the table columns. I don't think you are giving us enough context to answer your question

Comment: So I tested my LINQ query in a Console app and all the information I was seeking to join worked fine.

Comment: You need to show us the your entity models so we can see the relationships between them. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a junction table that means that one product can have many authors, but the select you're using implies that there is only one author behind a product. If that is really the case, there's no need for a junction table. You could just set a authorId field in the product table.

A product needs a list of authors, not just one.

On a side note: Ideally you would want to seperate the concerns.

- Create a Model that maps to each table in your database.
- Create a Repository to get the data (with linq)
- Create a ViewModel for all possible views.
- Populate the ViewModel in the Controller
- Return the ViewModel to the View.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `anonymous` object in view this way. At first if you need create a `ViewModel`.

Example:
**ViewModel:**

```
public class ProductViewModel{
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string Start_FY { get; set; }
     public string ProductType { get; set; }
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var products = (from pd in db.tblProducts
join aupd in db.tblAuthorProducts on pd.Product_ID equals aupd.Product_ID
join au in db.tblAuthors on aupd.Author_ID equals au.Author_ID
orderby pd.Product_ID
select new ProductViewModel
{
pd.Title,
pd.Description,
pd.Start_FY,
pd.ProductType,
au.FirstName,
au.LastName
}).ToList();

 return View(products);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Product ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)

{

    <tr>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        </tr>
}
</table>
```

although if you need to pass anonimus object to view you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43791585/asp-net-returning-multiple-variables-to-view/43792021#43792021) link.